# virtual inheritance with abstract class constructors

Tags: c++, oop

I got the following problem: There is an abstract base class, and two other abstract classes which virtually inherit from the base class, and as a conclusion have to call the Constructor of it, with all the needed arguments.

But now, I got a "normal" class which does inherit both second order classes, and therefor has to call the baseclass-constructor on its own (as the base class is inherited virtually from both the second order classes), but both of the second order constructors take arguments to pass on to the base class constructor.

Is it possible to somhow implement the constructors in a way that there will be no need to pass those, in that case unused, arguments?

I hope I was able to precisely describe my problem, if there are any questions I will be happy to answer them.

Comment: It sounds like you tried hard to describe it well, but if you could knock up a little code sample it might help us understand what you're doing a lot better to give better answers :)

Comment: sounds like `struct base { base(char a) {} virtual func()=0;}; struct derived1 : public virtual base { derived1() : base('a') {} func() {} }; struct derived2 : public virtual base { derived2() : base('b') {} func() {} }; struct derived3 : public derived1, derived2 { derived3() : derived1(), derived2(), base('c') {} };`?

Comment: I like the crazy code comment :)

Comment: Hmm, turns out I don't know enough about virtual inheritance to answer the question.  Off to study!

Comment: My only thought is to add protected constructors to the two derived classes to signify they don't have to construct the base class, but looking at the standard, I don't see anything clarifying the question.

Comment: I would recommend making your interfaces pure virtual.  Write dumb, concrete objects with the behavior you would like to share.  When you implement the interfaces you can compose the concrete objects to provide what you need.

Comment: `class a { int eins;int zwei;int drei; a(int a,int b,int c) : eins(a),zwei(b),drei(c) {}; virtual void f() = 0; }; class b : public virtual a { b(int a,int b,int c) : a(a,b,c); }; class c : public virtual a { c(int a,int b,int c) : a(a,b,c); }; class normal : public b, public c { normal(int a,intb,int c) : a(a,b,c), b(a,b,c),d(a,b,c) {};`
Here you can see, that the parameters needed for a, which is the base class, are also passed wastefully to b and c!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FINALLY* found it.

> § 12.6.2 / 7 [class.base.init]
>
> The expression-list or braced-init-list in a mem-initializer is used
>   to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a
>   delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the
>   initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.  The
>   initialization performed by each mem-initializer constitutes a
>   full-expression. Any expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as
>   part of the full-expression that performs the initialization. **A
>   mem-initializer where the mem-initializer-id denotes a virtual base
>   class is ignored during execution of a constructor of any class that
>   is not the most derived class.**

So, pass the arguments.  They'll be ignored anyway.  Makes things really simple!

Comment: hmm, ok! Will have to do that, but i actually hoped that there is some way around that so i could design short and precise constructors.

Comment: You could also make protected constructors that simply don't take those arguments, for use from a derived class.

Comment: A good question is, though, why is it required, even if the situation of calling this constructor is impossible. For example, why is it required that a constructor in an abstract class initialize the virtual base (i.e. when a virtual base has a constructor with arguments, then the default constructor in this abstract class cannot be synthesized and must be explicitly provided). When called from the deriving class, it won't be called because the deriving class must initialize the virtual base itself anyway. Otherwise it won't be called because the class is abstract.

Comment: @Ethouris: Sadly, the answer is it probably just wasn't worth the effort to write an exception for this case into the C++ spec.  "Base class has no default constructor, and middle class is virtual and abstract" probably doesn't come up often enough to bother.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It's very simple, it's enough to state that constructor delegation to the base class constructor is ignored (and need not be provided) for virtual bases, if the class is abstract. Someone should have forgot about that.